# reduceByKey is not a member

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Hi I have code simply get word counts from a document. I also need to use a map to look up the data value before generating the output. Here is the code.

```
   requests
    .filter(_.description.exists(_.length > 0))
    .flatMap { case request =>
      broadcastDataMap.value.get(request.requestId).map {
        data =>
          val text = Seq(
            data.name,
            data.taxonym,
            data.pluralTaxonym,
            request.description.get
          ).mkString(" ")
          getWordCountsInDocument(text).map { case (word, count) =>
            (word, Map(request.requestId -> count))
          }
      }
    }
    .reduceByKey(mergeMap)
```

The error message is

```
reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]]]
```

How can I resolve this? I do need to call getWordCountsInDocument. Thanks!

Comment: you need get PairRDD. Try to use .map() before reduceByKey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reduceByKey is a member of PairRDDFunctions, basically it gets added implicitly to RDDs in the form `RDD[(K, V)]`. You probably need to flatten out the structure to be an `RDD[String, Map[Int,Int]]`.

If you can provide the types for your inputs (`requests`, `broadcastDataMap` and `mergeMap`) we may be able to provide some help with that conversion.

From the types provided, and an assumption that the return type of getWordCountsInDocument is some Collection[(word, count: Int)]

Changing:

```
broadcastDataMap.value.get(request.requestId).map {
```

to

```
broadcastDataMap.value.get(request.requestId).flatMap {
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. #1: requests is an RDD of request, which has (requestId, description) #2: broadcastDataMap is broadcast of Map[requestID, Data(name, taxonym, pluralTaxonym)] #3: mergeMap is a function that takes two Map[Int, Int] and returns one Map[Int, Int]: private def mergeMap(map1: Map[Int, Int], map2: Map[Int, Int]): Map[Int, Int] = {
    (map1 ++ map2).map { case (key, _) =>
      (key, map1.getOrElse(key, 0) + map2.getOrElse(key, 0))
    }
  }